# How to work with the data warehouse in the application with tasks (real time)?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vuex

I study Vue and Vuex. In the official documentation there is a [simple example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html) of using a Vuex with saving data to localStorage.

To better understand the material I studied, I decided to consolidate the knowledge into practice and write a mini application - a clone of trello (SPA).
Namely:

1. Create three routes:

- General dashboard (/dashboard) where are boards
- Board (/board) where one or several columns are located, each column has a button for
  creating a task in it
- Task (/:task-id) that are in columns, tasks can be moved between columns

2. Sidebar in which all notice with the board are displayed (CRUD by tasks and columns, changes in the status of a task, and so on.)
3. Sockets so that other users can see the
   changes on the board in real time.

**Questions!**

1. What data should I store exclusively in the storage Vuex? Excluding authorization. It is obvious.
2. For what data in this application can localStorage be useful?
3. What should I use so that data is not discarded when I refresh the page or navigate? I can use localStorage, but hypothetically there can be a lot of data. The fourth question follows from this.
4. Is a better solution to use persistent remote storage on server / cloud? If so, could you give me information on how to do this? And in this case, interaction with the database is of interest, at what point is it better to save data in the database?

I'm interested in how to properly build such an application, as in a real commercial application.

I use and learn the stack MEVN

Answer (score 0):

1- you can store any type of data in your store, 2 - I don't thing is useful. Because if users remove browser cache all them data will be forget. So you need configure an database for this. 3 -  You need a Database and some Backend to provide your data. 4 - It's depends. if you need only for developement, you can install any things in your machine. If you need some thing more robust, could you take a cloud server. But for configure the server you need a little bit system administrator skills.